# Google App Engine RuntimeHelper.checkRestricted taking 25X time from antlr GAE Java 1.7

Tags: java, google-app-engine

We are using antlr parsing on GAE 1.7 and find a 25x overhead (running GAE in eclipse locally compared to running a standalone Java app) because it spends 96% of its time in RuntimeHelper.checkRestricted

(We are NOT in GAE 1.6.4 which had a bug of extra calls to RuntimeHelper.checkRestricted)

Does anyone know a list of which method calls trigger calls to RuntimeHelper.checkRestricted so that we can potentially avoid those please?  For some reason I can't find any documentation of this security manager and what triggers it.

One call which repeatedly triggers a time-consuming call to checkRestricted seems to be
antlr.runtime.DFA.predict(IntStream)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you know if you are using BCrypt? Others were experiencing similar problems when using BCrypt. Google has since fixed the the BCrypt issue: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7277&thanks=7277&ts=1333530915 How do things look for you now?